# Issue with Laravel Eloquent Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

I have the following setup, three tables, `tracks`, `tags` and `tag_track`

**`tracks`**

```
CREATE TABLE `tracks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mdbid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `track_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sort_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `safe_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `album_mdbid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tracks_mdbid_unique` (`mdbid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=603 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**`tags`**

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mdbid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tags_mdbid_unique` (`mdbid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tags_text_unique` (`text`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3376 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**`tag_track`**

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_track` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_mdbid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `track_mdbid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tag_track_tag_mdbid_index` (`tag_mdbid`),
  KEY `tag_track_track_mdbid_index` (`track_mdbid`),
  CONSTRAINT `tag_track_track_mdbid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`track_mdbid`) REFERENCES `tracks` (`mdbid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tag_track_tag_mdbid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_mdbid`) REFERENCES `tags` (`mdbid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**`Track`**

```
class Track extends \Eloquent {

  // Add your validation rules here
  public static $rules = [
    // 'title' => 'required'
  ];

  // Don't forget to fill this array
  protected $fillable = [];

    public function album() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Album', 'album_mdbid', 'mdbid');
    }

    public function getTags() {
        return $this->hasMany('Tag', 'tag_track', 'tag_mdbid', 'track_mdbid');
    }

}
```

**`Tag`**

```
class Tag extends \Eloquent {

  // Add your validation rules here
  public static $rules = [
    // 'title' => 'required'
  ];

  // Don't forget to fill this array
  protected $fillable = [];

    public function getTracks() {
        return $this->hasMany('Track', 'tag_track', 'tag_mdbid', 'track_mdbid');
    }
}
```

**`Routes`**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    // When I uncomment the line below it finds the tag details
    // $tag = Tag::where('mdbid', '=', 'mR3YQxbayRP1RwGzvEJvXe1BcFPukMSP');
    $track = Track::find(1);
    return $track->tags;
});
```

When I go to the route in the browser, nothing is shown

**UPDATE**

I have now got it displaying the correct number of results, but only after changing the pivot table to integers, before I was using a 32 length alphanumeric field. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Change getTags() to tags() on the Track model, or use $track->getTags like you defined on the model.

And since you have many-to-many relationship between tags and tracks, change the definitions:

```
// on Tag model
public function getTracks() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Track', 'tag_track', 'tag_mdbid', 'track_mdbid');
}


// on Track model
public function getTags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tag_track', 'track_mdbid', 'tag_mdbid');
}
```

And why you don't want to setup relation on the primary ids but mdbids?

Comment: This doesn't show anything. I get an empty JSON object.

Comment: run DB::getQueryLog(); in the end and check the query, then run it in your db to ensure you have data to retrieve

Comment: Where do I put this? I have set up a route `db` to return DB::getQueryLog(); but it doesn't show anything

Comment: I have now returned three results... (which is correct) `//$track = Track::whereMdbid('2CLc8V5frNy3U0UzjyXvATPWhUGu0Y2z');
    $track = Track::find(1);
    return $track->tags;` but I can't specify the track?

Answer (score 0):

try renaming the function `getTags()` to `tags()` and then use

```
$track->tags()->getResults();
```

the `tags()` function will return a HasMany object this object represent the many to many relation the `getResults()` function return the results of the relation that means the tags related to the track in your case.
I hope this will be helpful

Comment: @Mike try it with $track->tags()->getResults();

Comment: All I see is an empty JSON object.

Comment: that means the relation is working, be sure that you have data on your database

Comment: There is data there, but I am not getting the relevant track back

Answer (score 0):

The relationship to use for a many-to-many is `belongsToMany()` and you've also got some foreign keys out of order.

Change `getTracks()` to `return $this->belongsToMany('Track', 'tag_track', 'track_mdbid', 'tag_mdbid');`

Change `getTags()` to `return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tag_track', 'tag_mdbid', 'track_mdbid');`

Additionally as others have pointed out, you must change these function names to `tags()` and `tracks()` or call them appropriately when trying to use them.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    // When I uncomment the line below it finds the tag details
    // $tag = Tag::where('mdbid', '=', 'mR3YQxbayRP1RwGzvEJvXe1BcFPukMSP');
    $track = Track::find(1);
    return $track->getTags;
});
```

Comment: That would seem as though the relationship is working.  Be sure you have some valid records in your database for `tag_mdbid` of id 1 and corresponding tracks that are linked to those.

Comment: When I uncomment the line `$tag = Tag::where('mdbid', '=', 'mR3YQxbayRP1RwGzvEJvXe1BcFPukMSP');` it pulls details of the tag, the pivot table is based off of the two `mdbids` (32 alphanumeric character)

Comment: It works when the `tag_mdbid` and `track_mdbid` in the pivot table are integers, but not when they are alphanumeric IDs. Any reason why?